# How to call stored procedure inside stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am defining one user defined table type in SQL Server 2008.

This is the code

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PayElementTable] AS TABLE(
    [EffDate] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PayEle] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ComType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Oper] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [Rowno] [varchar](10) NULL
)
GO
```

Then I create a procedure `sptemptable`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sptemptable
        @T PayElementTable Readonly,--user type as parameter
    @CTCID int
    AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

END
GO
```

What I want to do is I want to pass datatable as `@T` from C# and loop through the `@T` records inside above stored procedure and with in that loop I want to call another stored procedure with parameter and how to pass parameter to that procedure.

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of calling a stored procedure in a loop you should try and find a set based solution that processes all rows together if possible.

Comment: Thanks martin for guiding me but i don't know any set based solution that process all rows together pls guide me if you know

Comment: Would need to know what the stored procedure does. You might find this handy http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling Stored Procedure inside another one :

```
Execute yourSPName [coma separated parameter value list]
```

Loop in records of a table :

[Using Cursor in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: how to loop of all the record in @T table

Comment: You need to use Cursor to loop in your table records. Edited solution to provide a link about using Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the cursor . It is costly operation use while loop for iterating the records with counter variable