# How do you write sql code to accept aggregate functions in subquery?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code that keeps throwing this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Code:

```
SELECT (SELECT SumOfAmount 
        FROM (SELECT SUM(Proposals.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
            FROM Proposals
            WHERE Proposals.EstCloseDate Between DATEADD(YEAR,-0, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, +12, GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY Proposals.SalesRep, Proposals.ProposalStatus
            HAVING Proposals.ProposalStatus = 3) Proposals
            ), 
        (SELECT SumOfEstAmount
        FROM (SELECT Sum(Prospects.EstAmount) AS SumOfEstAmount
            FROM Prospects
            WHERE Prospects.ProspectStatus = 1  AND 
            Prospects.EstProposalDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR,-0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(YEAR,+12, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())) 
            GROUP BY Prospects.SalesRep) Proposals
            )   

FROM Proposals
INNER JOIN SalesRep ON Proposals.SalesRep = SalesRep.SalesRepID
INNER JOIN Prospects ON Proposals.Amount = Prospects.EstAmount
GROUP BY Prospects.SalesRep, Proposals.SalesRep, Proposals.ProposalStatus,Proposals.Amount
```

Comment: Well....you have aggregates here with grouping which means you have multiple rows being returned. You probably just need to get rid of all those crazy subqueries and do the aggregation in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the GROUP BY in the sub-selects you are getting more than one row which is used in the select-list of the main query.

Use a CASE to sum only some of the values instead of using sub-selects.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN P1.ProposalStatus = 3 AND
                  P1.EstCloseDate Between DATEADD(YEAR,-0, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, +12, GETDATE())
             THEN P1.Amount
             ELSE 0
             END) AS SumOfAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN P2.ProspectStatus = 1  AND
                  P2.EstProposalDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR,-0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(YEAR,+12, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()))
             THEN P2.EstAmount
             ELSE 0
             END) AS SumOfEstAmount
FROM
    Proposals P1
    INNER JOIN SalesRep S ON P1.SalesRep = S.SalesRepID
    INNER JOIN Prospects P2 ON P1.Amount = P2.EstAmount
GROUP BY P2.SalesRep, P1.SalesRep, P1.ProposalStatus
```

Also, don't group by `Amount`, since you want to sum it. Also joining on `Amount` looks quite strange; however, I don't know what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Honestly Olivier, really interested using stored procedure fields in other store procedure, but haven't found it yet. The subqueries are from stored procedures.

Comment: There is no stored procedure involved here. Simply a SELECT statement.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to use stored procedure parameters in another store procedure?

Comment: See [How to call stored procedure inside stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764067/how-to-call-stored-procedure-inside-stored-procedure)

Comment: Thanks Oliver, figured it out with your suggestions. :)

Answer (score -1):

key answer is "top 1". if you use sub query you should use top 1 in it

Comment: This will for sure stop the query from blowing up and sometimes it makes sense, but blindy putting it in every single subquery can cause problems. It's often better for the query to fail rather than silently giving incorrect results.